# How do I handle a multiple select form field in python + webapp2?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2, webapp2

I have a form built with python + webapp2 + jinja2. All the values submitted appear to be strings. One of the fields is a multiple select and only the first selected item gets submitted. Is there a way to have that field submitted as an array of all the selected values.

I have for the html template

```
<select name="some_list" multiple>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="red">Blue</option>
  <option value="red">Yellow</option>
</select>
```

In the python class

```
some_list = []
some_list = self.request.get('some_list')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The request object contains a [MultiDict](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html#get-data) which means you can use another method to get all values passed for a given key. Try something like:

```
self.request.params.getall('some_list')
```